# CSS Body background image is cut off when scrolling viewport

Tags: html, css

(This is a better rephrase of my [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336761/background-image-is-cut-off-at-bottom-or-right-when-scrolling-viewport) - you can mark the other one as a duplicate of this one. Thanks)

I saw quite a few similar questions but could not find a fix. Open [this sample](https://glaring-inferno-4496.firebaseapp.com/) and resize the browser to make its height shorter than the main div height (~400 pixels).
When scrolling down, the background image attached to the body is cut off.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}
body { 
  height:100%; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
  background:url(bg.jpg) repeat-x; 
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: contain;
}
/*#pageWrap { background:url(bg.jpg) repeat-x;}*/
#page {
  height:100%;
}
#divHeader { 
  width:100%; 
  height:115px; 
}
#divMain {
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  border: solid 1px brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="pageWrap">
      <div id="page">
        <div id="divHeader">Header</div>
        <div id="divMain">Main</div>
        <div id="divFooter"><p>All Rights Reserved. Blabla® 2015</p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to move the background image to the `pageWrap` div as someone suggested.
It solves the vertical scroll problem, but creates a similar problem horizontally: When the window is too narrow and you scroll left, the image is cut off on the right.

Any real solution?

Comment: Have you given any thought to just styling the background color using css?  It would eliminate that completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest replacing your background image with a CSS gradient, this might seem difficult but there is [a fantastic tool](http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,cccccc+96,cccccc+100) that does it all for you (they also show a browser support table below the tool!)

The output CSS for a gradient that you'd want looks like this:

```
background: rgb(0,0,0); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 96%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 96%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 96%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Furthermore, you might want to remove `height: 100%` on the html and body for `min-height: 100%` since you'll want this gradient to stretch out over the length of this page.

The reasons you'd want to use a gradient over an image is just purely because it replaces a request to a ~100-300kb image with **no request** and only ~100-300b added to your CSS which I think is a good trade off against almost any criteria.

The tool also has support for importing an image, you can basically take your image, upload it and get a gradient out of it that comes closer to a perfect result than you could ever do by hand.

Comment: Thanks I accepted your answer and adopted the method.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could remove the height:100% from HTML, BODY and #page, and then set background-color on the body to #3E3E3E (in this example).

The difference is that the background image would not stretch all the way down, but it would remove the scrolling problems.

Height:100% only applies to 100% of the height of the browser window, not the height of the page within the browser window - that's why you;re getting the white area below when you scroll down.

Comment: Thanks your answer is good but I accepted Sidney's answer as it refers to my specific case of a gradient background, and adds the cool CSS hint.